# Devise after_sign_in_path_for ... sending to .... root_path - query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, routes

I need help with a routes issue with devise authentication gem to redirect to a custom page after successful login so as to create a new record by entering a test person name and age ( test data )

I am using Rails 3 with devise version 1.4.9

My routes are as below

```
    new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
        user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
       user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
   new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
  edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
                     PUT    /users/password(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
   cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        {:action=>"cancel", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
   user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
   edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
                     PUT    /users(.:format)               {:action=>"update", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
                     DELETE /users(.:format)               {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
             testers GET    /testers(.:format)             {:action=>"index", :controller=>"testers"}
                     POST   /testers(.:format)             {:action=>"create", :controller=>"testers"}
          new_tester GET    /testers/new(.:format)         {:action=>"new", :controller=>"testers"}
         edit_tester GET    /testers/:id/edit(.:format)    {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"testers"}
              tester GET    /testers/:id(.:format)         {:action=>"show", :controller=>"testers"}
                     PUT    /testers/:id(.:format)         {:action=>"update", :controller=>"testers"}
                     DELETE /testers/:id(.:format)         {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"testers"}
                root        /                              {:controller=>"testers", :action=>"index"}
```

In applications controller i tried to override the method like below but to no avail i still get routed back to tester index

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protect_from_forgery

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource) 

      new_tester_path

  end

end
```

In my routes.rb file i have the below lines

```
Testing::Application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users 

  resources :testers

  root :to => 'testers#index'
```

While much of the code was done with scaffolding I was still not be able to figure how to redirect to **new_tester_path** or route **/testers/new** after **successful sign_in** by user email and password.

Can someone please let me know what i am missing..... while writing the override function, I  would like to know the exact route i need to specify.

While testing i tried something stupid like this but the google page is also not opening ... :(

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base 

protect_from_forgery 

helper ApplicationHelper

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource) 

"www.google.com" 

end 

def after_sign_up_path_for(resource) 

"www.google.com" 

end 

def after_update_path_for(resource) 

"www.google.com" 

end
```

Comment: While testing i tried something stupid like this but the google page is also not opening ... :(                                                class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  helper ApplicationHelper
  
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope) 
#      new_tester_path
       "http://www.google.com"
  end
  
 def after_sign_up_path_for(resource_or_scope)
         "http://www.google.com"
 end
 
 def after_update_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  "http://www.google.com"
 end

Answer (score 26):

Just use this snippet:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    def after_sign_in_path_for(user)
        user_url(user)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 6):

Try setting user_return_to path in session:

```
session['user_return_to'] = new_tester_path
```

You can do it in a controller derived from Devise::SessionsController

Comment: i tried this and the routes worked for me                                             def stored_location_for(resource)
    nil
  end

Answer (score 2):

The Devise documentation explains all the steps to [redirect to a specific page on successful sign in](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in). By combine the techniques, you can redirect a user to many places after successful sign in.

Here is the resume:

You can do this in a controller you inherit from Devise::SessionsController - first, in controllers/users/sessions_controller.rb:

```
module Users
  class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
   def new
     if params[:redirect_to].present?
       self.resource = resource_class.new(sign_in_params)
       store_location_for(resource, params[:redirect_to])  
     end
     super
   end
  end
end
```

In config/routes.rb, you would have also added:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {sessions: 'users/sessions'}
```

And you must add a custom after_sign_in_path_for in your ApplicationController

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protected
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    stored_location_for(resource) || root_path
  end
end
```

This works in all Devise versions, as I know.

Comment: Are you sure it is `new` and not `create`? How would you have `sign_in_params` available when you `GET` the `#new` route?

Comment: For me, redefining `new` didn't work, but moving the same logic under `prepend_before_action :redirect_to_saved_route, only: [:new]` did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is an inheritance issue. after_sign_in_path_for is originally defined within Devise::SessionsController. You can override it by making your SessionsController inherit from Devise::SessionsController, and then re-defining it within that controller.

Answer (score 1):

If you are having issues trying to override the `after_sign_in_path_for` or `after_sign_out_path_for` helper methods within the ApplicationController of a Rails engine, you may want to check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18473410/1241271).

It describes how you'll need to override the SessionsController in your engine instead of the ApplicationController.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be doing anything wrong. Maybe this is a Devise issue.

Can you please try to isolate this on a Rails app and open an issue on Devise ?

Comment: i tried to override the below function before ater_sign_in_path           def stored_location_for(resource)
    nil
  end   ---- and it just worked -- found this function in one of the thread relating to devise problem on stackoverflow