# Devise redirection issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using devise in my rails3 project. I need to redirect user to different page once logged-in. Without overriding sessions controller how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/12854498/790737

Try putting this in you ApplicationController:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    different_page_path  # this should be a path helper
end
```

I assume you know how to use path and url helpers, and that you can use

```
rake routes
```

to list them. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I will try this today and accept it Branderhost :)