# Devise after sign in/out inside of Mountable Engine redirecting to parent app rather than Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, rails-engines

After sign in or sign out with Devise, I'm redirected back to the parent app root_path rather than my engine's root path (or, as you can see below, where I tried to specify it to home_path).

Engine routes:

```
MyEngine::Engine.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, { 
    :class_name => "MyEngine::User",
    :module => :devise
  }

  get '/' => 'home#index', as: :home
  root :to => 'home#index'

end
```

Engine Application Controller:

```
module MyEngine
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

    def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
      home_path
    end

  end
end
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

The problem was not having namespaced the sessions controller. Specifying the controller explicitly in the engine, and having it namespaced correctly fixed the issue.

Routes:

```
MyEngine::Engine.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, { 
    :class_name => "MyEngine::User",
    :module => :devise,
    :controllers => { :sessions => "my_engine/sessions" }
  }
end
```

SessionsController in 'controllers/my_engine/sessions_controller':

```
module MyEngine
  class SessionsController < ::Devise::SessionsController

  end
end
```

Comment: This worked great! Just to clarify - be sure to override the private method  `after_sign_in_path_for` within the namespaced SessionsController.